# How to accommodate None types when comparing dates in SQL Alchemy Query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My query:

```
abandoned_days = 10
abandoned_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=abandoned_days)

abandoned_requests = db.query(models.DocumentRequest)\
    .filter(
        models.DocumentRequest.case_id.in_([case["id"] for case in cases]),
        models.DocumentRequest.status == 'requested',
        models.DocumentRequest.requested_at < abandoned_date) \
    .all()
```

My Error: `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'`

`abandoned_date` will always be a datetime type, however how can I make this database query to not query a record when it's requested_at value is `none` (or in SQL, `null`). But also still request records using the `models.DocumentRequest.requested_at < abandoned_date` line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many options how to achieve this.

***option 1: add filter to exclude such rows**

```py
    .filter(
...
        models.DocumentRequest.requested_at != None,  # new filter
        models.DocumentRequest.requested_at < abandoned_date,
    ).all()
```

**option 2: convert those to the date which will fail the filter**

```py
    .filter(
...
        sqlalchemy.func.coalesce(models.DocumentRequest.requested_at, datetime.now()) < abandoned_date,
    ).all()
```